# How does GNU ld determine the order of input sections from different files being put into an output section?

Tags: gnu, ld, elf, riscv

I change only one assembly instruction in my RISC-V code from `la t0, SYMBOL1` to `la t0, SYMBOL2` and keep the rest unchanged. By `readelf` I find that sizes of `.text` section before and after the change are different.
I `objdump` the two `elf`s and find that they organized input sections from files in different order,
[image]

So how does the linker determine the order of input sections from different files being put into an output section? Will this different order lead to `.text` sections of quite different sizes (several hundreds bytes)?

Comment: Are `SYMBOL1` and `SYMBOL2` defined in the same section of the same `.o` file?

Comment: looks like `SYMBOL1` and `SYMBOL2` have completely different definitions.

Comment: @АлексейХилаев Yes, they have different definitions. But I wonder why a single instruction will cause so large a difference.

Comment: @EmployedRussian They are not in the same section of the same `.o`. `SYMBOL1` is defined in a C file, and `SYMBOL2` is defined in the linker script.

Comment: unless otherwise specified (linker script) the order on the gnu linker command line determines the order that they are added to the binary.

Comment: where does the symbol live? do you have some link time optimizations on does this cause a formerly unused object to now be included?

Comment: `SYMBOL1` is defined in C source file and `SYMBOL2` is defined in linker script. I finally find that the large difference in `.text` size before and after the change is caused by an inline assembly code `asm volatile(".align 10");`. I changed the symbol and objects order is rearranged by linker, so that inline assembly code may lead to padding of different sizes. And now I still wonder what rules linker depends on to determine the order.